# Exporting a GeoTIFF from Google Earth Engine to Google Drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, google-drive

I am trying to export my EVI analysis from GEE as a GeoTIFF and bring it into ArcGIS Pro. I have looked at many tutorials and have no idea why this won't work...I am not getting any error messages, it just will NOT export to my Google Drive from GEE... Here is my code. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var collectionID = 'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA'
var startDate = '2020-05-01'
var endDate = '2020-05-30'

var data = ee.ImageCollection(collectionID)
          .filterBounds(area)
          .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
          .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 10)
          .median();
print(data)

var FCC ={ bands: ['B5','B4','B3'],min:0, max: 0.3};
Map.addLayer(data,FCC,'Landsat8');

var evi = data.expression(
  '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
    'NIR' : data.select('B5'),
    'RED' : data.select('B4'),
    'BLUE' : data.select('B2')
});
print(evi)

Map.addLayer(evi, {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'brown', 'yellow', 'green']}, 'EVI');

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: collectionID,
  description: 'Y2020M05',
  scale: 30,
  region: area
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the image you are exporting should be `evi` :

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: evi,
  description: 'Y2020M05',
  scale: 30,
  region: area
});
```